# How to mock a class that's a property on another class in TypeScript and Jest?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I'm currently writing tests for my controller and I want to mock the service the controller is using. It is currently a property on the class and I want to be able to mock this property. I've also tried creating a spy for the getter for this service but have had no luck.

I currently have a class GeneratorController:

```
export class GeneratorController extends Controller {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.service = new GeneratorService();
    this.getService = this.getService.bind(this);
  }

  public getService(): GeneratorService {
    return this.service;
  }

  private service: GeneratorService;
}
```

And a class GeneratorService:

```
export class GeneratorService implements Service {
  public save(item) {
    ...implementation
  }
}
```

I currently want to create tests for the controller and mock this service as it makes calls to my database. I currently have the folder structure:

generator

```
  |
  L__mocks__
  |  |
  |  LGeneratorService.ts
  |
  LGeneratorController.ts
  LGeneratorController.test.ts
  LGeneratorService.ts
```

In this mocks folder the GeneratorService looks like:

```
export const mockSave = jest.fn();

const serviceMock = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
  return { save: mockSave };
});
export default serviceMock;
```

And in GeneratorController.test.ts

```
import { GeneratorController } from "./GeneratorController";
import serviceMock, { mockSave } from "./__mocks__/GeneratorService";

jest.mock("./GeneratorService");

describe("Generator Controller", () => {
    describe("generate", () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
      serviceMock.mockClear();
      mockSave.mockClear();
    });

    it("Should generate", async () => {
      const controller = new GeneratorController();
      expect(mockSave).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

The issue I'm having now is whenever I run the test, it errors out:

```
TypeError: GeneratorService_1.GeneratorService is not a constructor
```

And then it shows an error on the initialization of GeneratorService().

Is there a solution to this error or a better way to mock this class? I've tried creating a spy on the getService() but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Invert the dependency. Newing up collaborators in the constructor makes it highly coupled and much harder to test.